# Symfony 3 advice : retrieve data from another entity

Tags: entity, symfony-3.2

I am new to Symfony and I was wondering how I would achieve this : I'm retrieving data from one entity, and one field is in JSON. It references data from other entities that I would like to convert into objects. Here is an example :

```
// JSON received
{items:"221,223",level:1,places:"12,15,17"}
```

I want this to be turned into :

```
Array(
    'items' => array(
        0 => Object(MyBundle/Entity/Item),
        1 => Object(MyBundle/Entity/Item)
    ),
    'level' => 1,
    'places' => array(
        0 => Object(MyBundle/Entity/Place),
        1 => Object(MyBundle/Entity/Place)
    ),
)
```

What would be the best practice way of retrieving these `Item` objects as calling an entity from another entity is not a good idea ?

I thought of serializing them as the embedded objects will be rather small, but is it the best solution ?

The JSON could contain many other entities, or none, the content is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up serializing my objects and saving them in the database. The whole process is managed by Symfony itself, as the field in the table has been declared as `object`.

I don't know if this is the preferred way of doing it but it perfectly fits my needs, and AFAIK it doesn't break any logic.

Moreover the objects that are serialized are really small so for the moment I don't see any drawback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use OneToMany relation for you entity. It Will give you an array of objects.
Check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: Thanks, the entity already has a OneToMany relation. I think I wasn't accurate enough in my question, I'm editing it as the JSON object will contain other entities, not only one.